# Is there a short way to check the non-equivalence of each variables from each other in R?

Tags: r, equality

While trying to solve the following logic problem in R, I faced this situation:

Five athletes (whose shirt numbers are 1,2,3,4,5) participate in a race, and they are given scores that are multiplication of their shirt number with the rank that they finished the race; i.e., if athlete with shirt number 2 finishes 5th, he gains 2*5=10 points.
The athlete with shirt number 1 didn't finish race as 4th and 5th.
The sum of the total score of these 5 athletes after the race is 41.
Find the ranks each athlete finished the race.

I finished the problem with the following code, and noticed that in case one faces more than 5 variables, checking the non-equivalence of all of them from each other can be very cumbersome. For example, in 10 variables, it requires C(10,2)=45 comparisons.

```
for (o in as.integer(1:5)) {
  for (t in as.integer(1:5)) {
    for (th in as.integer(1:5)) {
      for (f in as.integer(1:5)) {
         for (fi in as.integer(1:5)) {
if (o+2*t+3*th+4*f+5*fi == 41 && 
(o != 4 && o != 5) && 
# To check the following way in more complex cases is non-useful
((o!=t) && (o!=th) && (o!=f) && (o!=fi) && (t!=th) && (t!=f) && (t!=fi) && (th!=f) && (th!=fi) && (f!=fi))) {print(c(o,t,th,f,fi))}  
    }}}}}
#     o t th f fi
# [1] 2 5 4 3 1
```

Is there a short way to check the non-equivalence of each variables from each other in R?

Source (of the original problem):
[Mehmet Emrehan HALICI, "Brain Sport 1", 2019 (in Turkish)](https://www.kitapsec.com/Products/Beyin-Sporu-1-Mehmet-Emrehan-Halici-Tubitak-Yayinlari-364048.html)

Comment: `all( (1:5) %in% c(o,t,th,f,fi))` would be a sufficient check. But you might want to read about factoradic numbers and their application.

Comment: The one who downvote the question, if you face ten variables, then will you write all C(10;2)=45 cases? You seem not to see the importance of the question!

Comment: I think the issue is that you post some code with no explanation exactly what you're doing. Also, the question(although you state is for your kid) is more like a homework question. Such questions are generally off-topic.

Comment: The use of `as.integer` is unnecessary, since `1:5` is already an integer vector, also because being an integer or float makes no difference to the arrithmetic, and finally because you are then comparing them with doubles anyway.

Comment: @AaronHayman Your solution `all( (1:5) %in% c(o,t,th,f,fi))` seems perfect for this situation, but I could not get "[1] 2 5 4 3 1" when I copy-paste and mount your code to the relevant place. I got empty row. I am trying to solve the issue.

Comment: @AaronHayman I solved the problem with your technique: `for (o in as.integer(1:5)) {
  for (t in as.integer(1:5)) {
    for (th in as.integer(1:5)) {
      for (f in as.integer(1:5)) {
         for (fi in as.integer(1:5)) {
if (o+2*t+3*th+4*f+5*fi == 41 && 
(o != 4 && o != 5) && 
( all( (1:5) %in% c(o,t,th,f,fi)) )) {print(c(o,t,th,f,fi))}  
    }}}}}` You can write your comment as a solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be the most memory efficient way since I am looking for all possible combinations but here is my initial thought of how would I approach this

```
#Get all possible combinations of ranks that can be taken
#Player 1 can take any place from 1:3, rest all can take any place from 1:5
df1 <- expand.grid(1:3, 1:5, 1:5, 1:5, 1:5)

#Find combinations where after multiplying by the scores sum of it is 41

df2 <- df1[colSums(t(df1) * 1:5) == 41, ]
#Or
#df2 <- df1[rowSums(t(t(df1) * 1:5)) == 41, ]

#Keep only the rows which have only unique combination of ranks
df2[!apply(df2, 1, anyDuplicated), ]

#    Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
#209    2    5    4    3    1
```

Comment: Why do a double transpose?

Comment: @NelsonGon since, we want to multiply `1:5` column-wise I transpose it first and to get the dataframe back in same structure I transpose it again. Although it can be avoided by using `colSums` instead, updated with that.

Comment: @RonakShah Thx for beautiful application of `expand.grid` and `apply`. Your solution is very pedagogic. For my 8-year kid, I will go with Aaron Hayman's solution for the time being.

Answer (score 2):

There is a package `permute` you can use:

```
library("permute")
d <- rbind(1:5, allPerms(5))
df <- as.data.frame(d)
names(df) <- c("o", "t", "th", "f", "fi")
subset(df, (o+2*t+3*th+4*f+5*fi == 41) &  (o != 4 & o != 5))

#> subset(df, (o+2*t+3*th+4*f+5*fi == 41) &  (o != 4 & o != 5))
#   o t th f fi
#48 2 5  4 3  1
```

Here is a variation (usable for other values of n):

```
n <- 5
d <- rbind(1:n, allPerms(n))
df <- as.data.frame(d)
names(df) <- paste0("r", 1:n)
subset(df, (d %*% (1:n) == 41) &  (r1 != 4 & r1 != 5))
```

or

```
n <- 5
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(1:n, allPerms(n)))
df <- subset(df, V1 < 4)
subset(df, as.matrix(df) %*% (1:n) == 41)
```

Comment: Very followable answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to make my own permutation function, so in reality it is probably simpler (and more efficient/safer) to use the `permute` package that jogo suggested.

The permution makes use of the principle of factoradic numbers that I refered to in my comment:

```
perm <- function(n, perm){
    pos=seq(n)
    res=integer(n)
    x=rev(seq(n))-1
    for(i in seq(n)){
        y  = 1 + perm%/%factorial(x[i])
        res[i] = pos[y]
        pos=pos[-y]
        perm = perm - factorial(x[i])*(y-1)
    }
    return(res)
}
ord = list()
for(i in seq(factorial(5))-1)
{
    p = perm(5,i)
    if(sum(p*1:5)==41 & p[1] < 4) ord =  append(ord,list(p))
}

ord
## [[1]]
## [1] 2 5 4 3 1
```

This solution is using nested for loops, so it really isn't that well suited to R, but is perhaps interesting from an algorithmic point of view.

Comment: you will get only the last solution in `ord`.

Comment: I know, but there is only one solution, I will edit to make it more general

Comment: I decided to change the name of the function after I wrote, but didn't update the call. Good catch

Answer (score 0):

Aaron Hayman's solution:

```
for (o in as.integer(1:5)) {
  for (t in as.integer(1:5)) {
    for (th in as.integer(1:5)) {
      for (f in as.integer(1:5)) {
         for (fi in as.integer(1:5)) {
if (o+2*t+3*th+4*f+5*fi == 41 && 
(o != 4 && o != 5) && 
( all( (1:5) %in% c(o,t,th,f,fi)) )) { # Trick
print(c(o,t,th,f,fi))}  
    }}}}}
# [1] 2 5 4 3 1
```

This solution worked well since the possible values of the variables (i.e., 1,2,3,4,5) are easy to handle with, and a check was made easily via `all( (1:5) %in% c(o,t,th,f,fi))`.